# How can i move element in map from it's current index to last available index

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i move element in map from it's current index to last available index

for example

```
Map myMap = {'name':'Alex','age':'30','color':'red'};
```

now lets say i want to replace `'age':'30'` with the last elemnt which is `'color':'red'` or whatever is the element

in other word replace it with last index what what ever the element is

so the final output is

```
{'name':'Alex','color':'red','age':'30',};
```

how could i handle it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rearrange map keys in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032554/how-to-rearrange-map-keys-in-dart)

Comment: no since that question ask for reverse the map

Answer (score 0):

There's no real efficient way to do this with a map, since pair index is not exposed.
However, it is accessible through the entries property. So moving element on index 1 to the end of the map can be achieved by:

```
MapEntry movedElement = myMap.entries.elementAt(1);
myMap.remove(movedElement.key);
myMap[movedElement.key] = movedElement.value;
```

The last line will always place a new element at the end.